# Meteor 1.4 : Mup deploy on Amazon EC2 : Error while verifying deployment

Tags: meteor, amazon-ec2, meteor-up

Im new to meteor, I have developed an meteor app and working fine locally. My configurations are below:

### Localhost

Operating system : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 
Metoer Version : Metoer 1.4, 
Node.js(ubuntu) : 4.4.3 (by executing command #nodejs -v), 
Node.js(npm)    : 3.10.6 (by executing command #npm nodejs -v)

### My requirements

1. Locally while running an app, I will execute the command (#meteor) inside the app directory later App will be running in http://localhost:3000
2. I want to deploy the meteor app into amazon EC2. I have installed meteor, mongodb on EC2, moved the same project folder to amazon ec2.
   Site is running when accessed as "www.mysitename.com:3000" by executing command (#meteor), but users wont always type the port number
3. I wanted to run the meteor app as "www.mysitename.com" and not as "www.mysitename.com:3000". If we want to host in remote server, should (#meteor) command should be always running?
4. I tried meteor-up with mup init, mup setup, mup deploy commands. Getting error while verifying deployment

   `$mup deploy
    update 1.0.2 => 1.0.3
    Building App Bundle Locally`

   `Started TaskList: Pushing Meteor
    [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server
    [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Pushing Meteor App Bundle to The Server: SUCCESS
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Pushing the Startup Script
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Pushing the Startup Script: SUCCESS
   { public: {} }

   Started TaskList: Configuring  Meteor Environment Variables
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Sending Environment Variables
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Sending Environment Variables: SUCCESS

   Started TaskList: Start Meteor
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Start Meteor
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Start Meteor: SUCCESS
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] - Verifying Deployment
   [ec2-54-199-248-21.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com] x Verifying Deployment: FAILED    `

   ```
   -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
   package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
   npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
   npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
   npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)
   => Starting meteor app on port:80

   assert.js:93
     throw new assert.AssertionError({
           ^
   AssertionError: "undefined" === "function"
       at wrapPathFunction (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:77:10)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/mini-files.js:108:24)
       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
       at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
       at require (module.js:380:17)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:9:13)
       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

   => Redeploying previous version of the app

   -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

   To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

My Mup.js file

```
module.exports = {
servers: {
    one: {
        host:       'amazon-aws-host-public-dns-name',
        username:   'username',
       //password:   '', // or leave blank for authenticate from ssh-agent
        pem:       '../permissionfile.pem' // or leave blankfor authenticate from ssh-agent
    }
},

meteor: {
    name: 'meteor-app-name',
    path: '/local-directory-of-meteor-app/meteor-app-name/', // localpath
    servers: {
        one: {
            host:       'amazon-aws-host-public-dns-name',
            username:   'username'
        },
    },
    env: {
        PORT: 80, // optional, defaults to 80
        ROOT_URL: 'http://amazon-aws-host-public-dns-name',
        MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://amazon-aws-host-public-dns-name/postAd', // postAd is the mongodb-name. I did not create the same in aws
        //MONGO_OPLOG_URL: 'mongodb://oplogUser:mongo@domain.co'
    },

    deployCheckWaitTime: 120 //default 10, if you're having issues try increasing this value up to 600 //
},
mongo: { //optional
    oplog: true,
    port: 27017,
    servers: {
        one: {},
    },
},
};
```

` 
5. Kindly guide me to clear the error and proceed with $mup deploy or suggest any alternate solutions, except hosting in galaxy,digitalocean etc.
6. Also, I used meteor command to deploy
   $meteor build /path
  I received a meteor-app-name.tar.gz. Can I use the compressed file to deploy it my amazon-ec2 ubuntu instance? Can anyone guide me on the same?

Comment: Did you install mongoDB and Meteor on the server then do mup setup & deploy?

Comment: I have documented steps to deploy meteor app on amazon. You can check them here  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/meteor/4773/beginner-guide-to-installing-meteor-1-4-on-aws-ec2#t=201608241707241133915  , let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @AGdev: Will check your document today.

Comment: @Luna: Meteor & Mongodb install in AWS Server.

Comment: Installed using mupx, solved the issue myself.